# labelling featres for classification using in Support Vectore Machine?

Tags: matlab, svm

I want to ask something..

If I extract HOG features from an image with cell size 8 and orientation bin = 8 , I will get N X M X 32 matrix.
And now, I want to train it with SVM, which will gives an label per row..

How I can make that 3d matrix into an row, so I can give an label in that row. Furthermore, that matrix along with its label will be train in SVM??

Here is my example:
label1 -> row 1 (features of image 1 N X M X32)
label2 -> row 2 (features of image 2 N X M X32)
.
.
.
and so on

Any idea??

Answer (score 1):

That's very simple.  Change the 3D matrix so that it is a vector.  That way you can define with each training label its associated HOG feature matrix and thus transformed vector.  You can now throw these training labels and associated vectors into your SVM model creation.

Suppose that `R` is your `N x M x 32` matrix.  If you did:

```
x = R(:);
```

This will create a vector which has `N x M x 32` elements long.  It will take each column of your matrix on a slice by slice basis and stack it so that it is a single vector.

If you repeat this for all of the HOG feature matrices that you have, you will have feature vectors and you can thus associate these with your training labels.  This should work well with HOG and I would recommend that you choose some sort of Radial Basis Function as the kernel when transforming the data into its associated hyperspace.

Comment: But the extracted features for each images have a different size. For example for image 1 using ur logic, the feature will be 10368 x 1, image 2 = 7200 x 1. When Im going to store it in each row in an matrix, I cannot because image 1 would be 1 x 10368, images 2 would be 1 x 7200.. How to save that different size of features in an image (by using loop)??

Comment: I assumed that every feature was the same length.  You didn't tell me that they were all different lengths.  Your post indicated that all of the matrices were the same sizes.  If they are all different lengths, then you're not creating your model right.  You need to use the same parameters for the HOG detection for every image that you use.  Otherwise there is no point in classification at all.

Comment: Of course it will be different. even if I used the same parameters, but the size of every images is different. So the extracted A X B X D is always be different..

Comment: I still don't think you are applying the principle right... either way, the SVM classifier requires that the feature vectors are all the same size before you train your model.  I've never heard of such a methodology where the size of each training vector is different with each label.  Also, you haven't told me how you're building the feature vector.  Are you taking blocks of image patches and making HOG features out of them?